# Impact of cardio during caloric surplus (Bulking phase)

Tags: cardio, sprinting, conditioning, bulking

> In two weeks: 5 sessions of intense cardio (sprinting) of 15 minutes
>   each; 9 sessions of moderate to heavy lifting of 45 minutes to 1 hour
>   each.

This is my planned schedule, all of it during a caloric surplus. Also, note that the cardio sessions are planned for my off days from lifting.
I've been working out for 3 months, in a bulking phase (no cardio), went from 123 lbs to 143 lbs (5'9 height). Noticing a bit of fat collecting on my belly area, the rest of the body looks fine. My questions are:

> 1. Would this plan be an optimal solution for increasing muscle mass while keeping fat gains to a minimum and reaping the other benefits of
>      cardio (I would not be eating at a deficit)?
> 2. Will this amount of cardio affect my muscle gains?
> 3. Should my pre and post workout meal remain same for the cardio sessions or what would be an ideal recommendation?
> 4. Is cardio, during a caloric surplus, worth it?

Also, my conditioning with respect to cardio is negligible. I do a desk job and don't have any other sports activity during the entire week.

My question is a direct reference to [this youtuber I follow.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz3AG-oCXTE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this plan be an optimal solution for increasing muscle mass while keeping fat gains to a minimum and reaping the other benefits of cardio (I would not be eating at a deficit)?

Only you can answer that question. Depends on how heavy you are lifting :). Lift heavy and do lots of it (high volume) and you'll build.

> Will this amount of cardio affect my muscle gains?

If you'll still be on caloric surplus, then absolutely not. Cardio will only make you feel more energetic and alive.

> Should my pre and post workout meal remain same for the cardio sessions or what would be an ideal recommendation?

You're just prematurely micro-optimizing at this point, my man. Eat at TDEE on cardio days, eat slightly more than TDEE on lifting days, moving most of your food post workout.

> Is cardio, during a caloric surplus, worth it?

Cardio is always worth it, despite all the bro-science memes against it. Just don't overdo it.

Comment: So, how many hours prior to cardio should I eat my last meal (last meal as in before cardio). Is there an ideal recommendation? I'd do cardio on late evenings if that helps.

Comment: Depends on your TDEE and when you go to the gym. If you're going to the gym first thing in the morning, then just have a few hundred calories (you don't need much because you are already energetic and rested from sleep. I'd recommend maybe a fruit+oat bowl) and a nice cup of black coffee. Go to gym, workout, then enjoy the rest of your calories as you please.